# MYSQL Use Index not working but Force index works?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have executed the below query but it takes 72sec to completed

```
SELECT ci.id, ci.city_real, co.country_name FROM cities ci 
LEFT JOIN countries co ON(ci.country_id=co.country_id) 
WHERE city_real in ('Delhi','Bangalore','Mumbai') ORDER BY population DESC
```

Then I have created indexes as per `explain` stat plan but it is no different which means it takes 72sec.

Then I have changed the query using `use index`

```
SELECT ci.id, ci.city_real, co.country_name FROM cities ci 
LEFT JOIN countries co use index (idx_name) ON(ci.country_id=co.country_id) 
WHERE city_real in ('Delhi','Bangalore','Mumbai') ORDER BY population DESC
```

this time also I am disappointed because this also takes 68 to 73 secs to complete.

Finally, I have used `force index` in my query

```
SELECT ci.id, ci.city_real, co.country_name FROM cities ci 
LEFT JOIN countries co force index (idx_name) ON(ci.country_id=co.country_id) 
WHERE city_real in ('Delhi','Bangalore','Mumbai') ORDER BY population DESC
```

Now I can see the result in just 7secs.

From this example my questions are:

- Why `use index` didn't work?
- When I use `force index` any side-effects will be occurred or not?

The number of rows in the table countries:- 1200000 rows
The number of rows in the table cities:- 45000000 rows

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables.  There may be a 'composite' index that will obviate the need for USE/FORCE.  Or, perhaps, a mismatch in collation.

Comment: 12 lakh???  There are only about 250 countries in the world.

Comment: @RickJames Due to security reasons I can't able to show the actually details that's why I am changing the table name. :)

Comment: Your output is 45M rows?  So much bulk will take minute(s).

Comment: Yes it's a big table that means it contains only 3 columns and 45M rows but I can get the result in 1.5 mins

Comment: I still need to see the indexes, even if the names are obfuscated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE INDEX you give mysql the chance to select another index if it calculates the other is better,

With FORCE INDEX, you force mysql to use it and it will do that.

side effects the query could be slower, than the chosen one by mysql, but when you want another because it choose wrong, you only can get slower

Answer (score 0):

Did you run each test twice?  I strongly suspect that the difference (10x) is not due to the use of an index hint, but from the caching of data.

You ran the `USE` with nothing in the buffer_pool.  So there was a lot of I/O to fetch the 45M rows from one table and 1.2M rows from the other.

Then you ran with `FORCE`, which worked the same way.  But this time, it found all the data in RAM.  So it ran 10 times as fast.

Further evidence can be found from `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  This will say which index it did use.